# Plotting the ROC curve

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing, detection, roc

If I have a matrix `A` of size `m x n`. The elements in the matrix represent the results of a specific detector.

What I want is to characterize the performance of the detector by an ROC curve (sensitivity or Probability of detection by function of the probability of False alarm or 1-specificity). Interestingly, when `(A(i,j) >= threshold) => the target is present`, `else it is absent`. But of course, there will be some errors like as False alarm (False Positive) or Miss (False Negative).

Lets first remember of two important equations:

```
Sensitivity = Probability of detection = TruePositive / (TruePositive + FalsePositive).
1-Specificity = Probability of False Alarm = TruePositive / (TruePositive + FalseNegative).
```

Now, I will give you what I tried to write in MATLAB, but what I want to know is how can I write both sections `1)` and `2)` of the code below in order to be able to draw a certain roc curve.

**My MATLAB code:**

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

NumOperation = 1;  % the number of operation to be achieved will increase by 1 for new value of Threshold. 

for Threshold = a:1:b; % So the threshold can take the values arranged from "a" to "b".

    Thresholding_result = zeros (m, n); % It is the matrix that will contain either zero (if the detection result in A is below a certain threshold) or 1 (if the detection result in A is above the threshold).

    Thresholding_result (find(A > Threshold)) = 1; % So the zero elements in the Thresholding_result matrix will be transformed to 1 when the corresponding values in A are above the Threshold.

    TruePositive = 0;
    FalsePositive = 0;
    TrueNegative = 0;
    FalseNegative = 0;

    for i = 1 : m
    for j = 1 : n

    if (Thresholding_result(i,j) == 1)

    % 1) so if we have 1, then there will be two options: either the target is really present ==> increasing the TruePositive by 1 (TruePositive = TruePositive + 1), or is not ==> increasing the FalsePositive by 1 (FalsePositive = FalsePositive + 1).
    end

    else if (Thresholding_result(i,j) == 0)

    % 2) so if we have 0, then there will be two options: either the target is really not present ==> increasing the TrueNegative by 1 (TrueNegative = TrueNegative + 1), or is not ==> increasing the FalseNegative by 1 (FalseNegative = FalseNegative + 1).

    end
    end
    end
TP_Matrix(NumOperation) = TruePositive / (TruePositive + FalseNegative);
FP_Matrix(NumOperation) = TruePositive / (TruePositive + True Negative);

NumOperation = NumOperation + 1;

end

% Plotting the ROC curve:
Plot((FP_Matrix), (TP_Matrix), 'b-'), xlabel('False Alarm'), ylabel('Probability of Detection');
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: If you have the statistics toolbox, you can simply use perfcurve.m

Comment: And how you can use this function?

Comment: The function's documentation ('doc perfcurve') includes a very simple to follow example of producing an ROC curve.