# wavelet decomposition of a vector

Tags: matlab, plot, haar-wavelet

If I have a hyperspectral data cube of size "`m x n x p`" where `m` is the row size, `n` represents the column size, while `p` is the total number of bands.

Lets denote the hyperspectral data cube by **A**. In this case, each pixel of **A** corresponds to a vector of size `p x 1`.

Ok to plot a pixel from **A**, we can do this:

```
specific_pixel = squeeze(A(x,y,:)); % Extracting a pixel located in the position x and y of A
plot(specific_pixel), ylabel('The specific pixel');
```

I have two questions:

1) I know how to plot each pixel separately like above, but how I can create a plot of all the pixels at meantime? for example if we have a 2D image, we can simply write plot(image). But for a datacube, how can we do this?

2) If I apply the 1D wavelet haar of 3 levels to the specific pixel above:

```
[c,s] = wavedec(A, 3, 'haar');
approxi = appcoef(c, s, 'haar', 3);
details3 = detcoef(c, s, 3);
details2 = detcoef(c, s, 2);
details1 = detcoef(c, s, 1);
```

How can I plot the concatenation of approxi and the three details??

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to plot 3D data.  You can either use [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) or [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) to achieve what you want.

With `plot3`, do:

```
plot(A(:,:,1), A(:,:,2), A(:,:,3), 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 10);
```

With `scatter3` do:

```
scatter3(A(:,:,1), A(:,:,2), A(:,:,3), 10, 'b');
```

The above code plots each point in 3D space at size 10 and in the colour blue.

With the second question, assuming that the output is also 3D, you can concatenate the cubes **horizontally** with [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html), then repeat the above code.

Something like this:

```
out = cat(2, approxi, details1, details2, details3);

plot(out(:,:,1), out(:,:,2), out(:,:,3), 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 10);
%// or
%// scatter3(out(:,:,1), out(:,:,2), out(:,:,3), 10, 'b');
```

The `2` parameter in `cat` concatenates horizontally, so you'd be piecing 4 cubes together horizontally, but still maintaining the same amount of dimensions in the third dimension, and then just plotting all of them at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciated it very much

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your question. If I did let me know but if this did answer your question, consider accepting my answer. Good luck!

Comment: Hallo, Ja of course I will accept your answer, but I just needed some hours to try to resolve some errors but I don't able to get the solution myself. In fact I am reading this article: http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1201/1201.2025.pdf , In the page 4, they mentioned the the DWT signal can be obtained by concatenating all the coefficients.

Comment: Let consider that I have a vector p of size ''126 x 1''. I applied the 3 level decomposition using daubechies16 (db16): $[c,s] = wavedec(p, 3, 'db16');
a3 = appcoef(c,s,'db16', 3);
d3 = detcoef(c,s,3);
d2 = detcoef(c,s,2);
d1 = detcoef(c,s,1);

p2 = cat(1, a3, d3, d2, d1);$

Comment: Unfortunately, the plot of the p2 don't give me a signal of size 126 x 1 like what they made in the article. What I made as wrong in my code ?

Comment: @Christina - Let me figure that out and get back to you.  Thanks for accepting my answer, though what I wrote wasn't correct!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I am also trying to resolve the problem :)

Comment: And please can you also try to help me here :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211461/plotting-the-roc-curve